# Why does this conversion in go from a rune-string to integer does not work?

Tags: string, go, int, rune, strconv

i have the following code:

I know about runes in go, i read about them a lot in the last hours i have tried to solve this...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    e := "\x002"
    fmt.Println(e)
    new := string(e)
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(new)
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err) }
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

result is:

2

strconv.ParseInt: parsing "\x002": invalid syntax

0

why can't i convert the string to an integer?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why are you not commenting or accepting ? Do you just like to ask questions or are you interested in the answers ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure of your goal but it looks like you want to extract the int value of the rune you get from a string containing a given character.

It looks like you want

```
e := "\x02"
runes := []rune(e)
i := runes[0]
fmt.Println(i) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`\xXXXX` tries to parse it as a unicode rune, you need to skip the `\` check [`this`](http://play.golang.org/p/QSyXzlGkSI):

Either use :

```
e := "\\x002"
#or use a raw string :
e := `\x002`
```

edit :

Why do you think `\x002` is a valid integer? do you mean `0x002`?